# Custom Validation error reporting in Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory to build some file to db imports and one of the requirements I have is if a file isn't valid. e.g. either a column is missing or contains incorrect data (wrong data type, lookup doesn't exist in a db) then an alert is sent detailing the errors. Errors should be regular human readable so rather than a SQL error saying insert would violate a forign key, it should say incorrect value entered for x.

This doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-data-flow-error-rows) describes a way of using conditional splits to add custom validation that would certainly work to allow me to import the good data and write the bad data to another file with custom error messages. But how can I then trigger an alert with this? As far as I can tell, this will result in the data flow reporting success and to do something like calling a logic app to send an email needs to be done in the pipeline rather than data flow.

Answer (score 0):

That’s a good point, but couldn’t you write the bad records to an error table/file, then give aggregated summary of how many records erred, counts of specific errors, that would be passed to logic app/SendGrid API to alert interested parties of the status. It would be post-data flow completion activity that checks to see if there is an error file or error records in the table, if so, aggregate and classify, then alert.

I have a similar notification process that gives me successful/erred pipeline notifications, as well as 30 day pipeline statistics... % pipeline successful, average duration, etc.

I’m not at my computer right now, otherwise I’d give more detail with examples.

Answer (score 0):

To catch the scenario when the rows copied and rows written  are not equal , may be you can use output of the copy active and if the difference is not 0 , send an alert .

[image]